# Octave matrix to image pixels too small (do not have 1 pixel per integer)

Tags: matrices, octave

I am working on a project which plots points over a checkerboard (representing seats for people).  I would like each pixel in the image to represent each integer matrix entry.  After updating my Octave from $3.8$ to $4.2$, any image takes up $\frac 14$ of the actual plot window, as seen here:

[image]

The simple code for this is as follows:

```
clear
hold off

A = [1,2;3,4];

image(A)

axis xy %orients to bottom left
```

Does anyone know how to get the image to take up the entire $2\times 2$ window, such that each pixel is the size of current image?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably better posted on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EthanBolker.  Thank you for the heads up.  Is there a way I can relay the question or does it need to be reposted entirely?

Comment: You could flag it for a moderator to migrate, but it's probably faster just to delete it here and post it there.